# Get position of many Qr codes in the same picture

Tags: image, encoding, zxing, detect

I'm actually working on a project which the subject is : Detection of multiple qr codes in the same picture. 
  I have succeed to encode all the qr codes using the ZXING (library java) but i have also get the position of each qr code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any idea from you would be appreciated